# Reference to member function

Tags: c++, reference, struct

first of all I know that this is not possible in C++. But I hope someone can tell be a workaround for my problem. I have a class which represents a mathematical function:

```
class myClass:
{
private:
public:
    myClass() {};
    double value(double, double){ /* doing some complicated calculation here */} };
    double integrate { /*calc*/ return integral; };
}
```

In `integrate()` I want to create a struct with a reference to `value()`. The struct is defined as follows:

```
struct gsl_monte_function_struct {
    double (*f)(double * x_array, size_t dim, void * params);
    size_t dim;
    void * params;
};
```

(I need this struct to call the Monte-Carlo integration routines from GSL)

As said before I know that this is forbidden in C++. But is there any possibility to use `gsl_monte_function_struct` with a member function of myClass? If it is not possible that `myClass` can integrate itself, is it possible to call `gsl_monte_function_struct` from outside the class with `value()` as reference? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so far I found two solutions:

1) (General solution) Using an abstract base class which has a static pointer to the current instance and a static function that calls a function of the derived class. The static function can be used with a function pointer.

Example:

```
struct gsl_monte{
   double (*f)(double y);
};

class myBase {
private:
  static myBase* instance;

public:
  myBase(){};
  static void setInstance(myBase* newOne);
  virtual double value(double x) =0;
  static double callValue(double x);//{return value(x);}
};

class myClass : public myBase {
   public:
      myClass(){};
      double value(double x) {  return x;  };
};

myBase* myBase::instance = new myClass();
double  myBase::callValue(double x){return instance->value(x);}
void myBase::setInstance(myBase* newOne){instance=newOne;};

double g(double xx) {return xx;};

int main(int argc, char** argv ){
   double x[2]; x[0]=1.3; x[1]=1.3;
   myClass* instance = new myClass();
   myBase::setInstance(instance);
   instance->value(3);
   std::cout << "Test " << myBase::callValue(5) << std::endl;
   gsl_monte T;
   T.f=&myBase::callValue;
   double (*f)(double y, void*) = &myBase::callValue;
}
```

2) (Solution specific to my problem) Fortunatly the desired function accepts a parameter pointer, which I can use to pass the current object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std::placeholders;

struct gsl_monte{
   double (*f)(double y, void*);
};

class myClass {
   public:
      myClass(){};
      double value(double x) {  return x;  };
};

double valueTT(double x, void* param) {  return static_cast<myClass*>(param)->value(x);  };

int main(int argc, char** argv ){
   double x[2]; x[0]=1.3; x[1]=1.3;
   myClass* instance = new myClass();
   instance->value(3);
   gsl_monte T;
   T.f=&valueTT;
   double (*f)(double y, void*) = &valueTT;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If understand you corretly, you want a pointer to a member function of `myClass`. You can achieve this by declaring the member function pointer as:

```
double (myClass::*value)(double,double)
```

This function can later be called on an instance as:

```
(instance.*value)(x,y);
```

Alternatively you can use `std::bind` to create a function object which can be called as an ordinary function without having to keep track of the instance on which it is called after the call to `std::bind`:

```
auto& value = std::bind(myClass::value, instance);
// ....
value(x,y);
```

Comment: It should be noted that invoking that member function pointer will require a pointer-to-member syntax, `->*` for example. There are examples of this on SO in several questions and answers.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's a good point. Which is why I included the mention of std::bind to be able to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: I tried: `auto d = std::bind(&myClass::value,instance,std::placeholders::_1);`. This works! But now I want to do: `double (*f)(double y) = d;` (this is the member function of gsl_monte_function). This fails! Any ideas?

Comment: The error is `stdbind_example.cpp:29:13: error: no viable conversion from 'std::__1::__bind<double (myClass::*)(double), myClass *&,
      std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &>' to 'double (*)(double)'
   double (*f)(double y) =d;`

Comment: @user2935834 The type of `d` is not actually a function pointer. It's a function object. You need to either make the gsl_monte_function_struct a template which depends on this type or use a member function pointer (double (myClass::*value)(double,double) and add a pointer to the instance (type myClass*) to your struct.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, what i want to do is impossible without changing `gsl_monte_function_struct`?

Comment: @hansgans That is correct. The reason is that your function is a member of a class, and it is not static. This means the function needs to know on which object it is being called. If you need to solve this without changing `gsl_monte_function_struct` you need to either make your function static or move it outside of the class. So, consider this: why is it a non-static member function?