# C++ class member function to GSL ODE solver

Tags: c++, class, pointers, ode, gsl

I am struggling with -- apparently -- a well known problem. I have an ODE system which is defined by a class member function, and I want to solve/integrate it by one of the GSL solvers. I.e., say my model is defined by:

```
class my_model{
...
public:
    int NEQ = 4;
    double y[4], dydt[4];
    double params[25]; 
    int ode_gsl(double t, const double y[], double dydt[], void * params);
    ...
};

int my_model::int ode_gsl(double t, const double y[], double dydt[], void * params){
    dydt[0] = params[1]*params[0]*y[0] - y[1];
    dydt[1] = ...;
    ...
    return GSL_SUCCESS;    
}
```

Then in my integration routine:

```
int main(){
    my_model chemosc;

   // Parameters for the Integrator
   double HSTART = 1e-3;
   double ATOL = 1e-8;
   double RTOL = 1e-6;

   // Instantiate GSL solver
   gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {&chemosc.ode_gsl, nullptr, chemosc.NEQ, chemosc.params};
   gsl_odeiv2_driver * d;
   d = gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new (&sys, gsl_odeiv2_step_rk8pd, HSTART, ATOL, RTOL);

   double twin[2] = {0.,60.};
   double dt = 1e-3;
   double t = twin[0], t1 = twin[1];
   long int NSTEP = (long int)((t1-t)/dt)+1; // +1 if you start counting from zero...
   int NEQ = 4;
   long int NUMEL = (NEQ+1)*NSTEP; // number of elements for solution

   int i = 0,j;
   do{
      double ti = t + dt; // t is automatically updated by the driver
      printf("\n%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f t%.3f",astro.y[0],astro.y[1],astro.y[2],astro.y[3]);
      int status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply (d, &t, ti, astro.y);
      ...
      }
...
}
```

Compiling the above code creates the somehow well known error that GSL requires a pointer-to-function whereas I am passing a pointer-to-member function, i.e.:

```
error: cannot convert ‘int (chemosc::*)(double, const double*, double*, void*)’ to ‘int (*)(double, const double*, double*, void*)’
```

I found several questions related to this topic: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679849/reference-to-member-function), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074756/how-to-avoid-static-member-function-when-using-gsl-with-c), [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450198/calling-gsl-function-inside-a-class-in-a-shared-library), [Q4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074756/how-to-avoid-static-member-function-when-using-gsl-with-c), [Q5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612873/gsl-odeiv2-in-c-class-template-wrapper-for-int-ode), [Q6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593726/a-function-pointer-issue-how-to-efficiently-interface-with-c-api-ie-gsl-from), but seriously, the answer there are hard to follow. Declaring as `static` my member function, has the downside that the compiler requires me to also declare as static all the member parameters. Using `static_cast` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593726/a-function-pointer-issue-how-to-efficiently-interface-with-c-api-ie-gsl-from), result in all bunch of segmentation errors (but I assume that I did something wrong in the implementation, inasmuch as the directions in that post are quite cryptic). It would be nice to have a once-for-all clear and as simple as possible working solution for this problem (possibly without using `boost` libraries).

Comment: Function signature seem to contain `void *` parameter that you can use to pass a pointer to a class instance (and whatever parameters you need). So you can declare a static member function (or non-member function) then cast `void *` parameter to the class instance and then invoke class member function that will do all the computations.

Comment: @VTT Yes, I kinda figure out that this is the way to proceed. But could you please give me come exemplifying code? What you say was mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593726/a-function-pointer-issue-how-to-efficiently-interface-with-c-api-ie-gsl-from, but again, it is related to integrators, rather than ODE solvers. And the explanation remains somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class my_model
{
    private: int
    ode_gsl_impl(double const t, double const * const y, double * const dydt);

    public: static int
    ode_gsl(double const t, double const * const y, double * const dydt, void * const opaque)
    {
        assert(opaque);
        return(static_cast<my_model *>(opaque)->ode_gsl_impl(t, y, dydt));
    }
};

gsl_odeiv2_system sys
{
    &my_model::ode_gsl
,   nullptr
,   chemosc.NEQ
,   reinterpret_cast<void *>(::std::addressof(chemosc))
};
```

I would like to mention that your original code suffers from name collisions between callback parameter names and class field names.

Comment: Yes. It works like a charm. Thanks. Very elegant trick and very concise and understandable.